# Java Servlets Convention

Tags: java, servlets

I have a question about Java servlets convention. In looking at any tutorial for servlets, whether it be Eclipse, NetBeans, etc., they always have you create an index.jsp page. Once the page is created, they have you create a form with a "submit" button that jumps you to the servlet for processing. My question is, in a servlets project, do you have to use the main index.jsp page, or can your project go immediately to the servlet?

I am working on my own little project to learn servlets, a project that connects to my local MySQL database, displays the list of schemas you can choose from, then displays the table data for each schema on the next page. In order to dynamically grab a list of schemas on the main page, I will need a servlet, not an index.jsp page. I know this can be done with JSP or JSF, but I would like to use servlets only.

This is where my original question comes in. Can my project go to an initial main servlet instead of an index.jsp page, or does convention, or technical matters, prohibit this?

Thank you for taking the time to read. Have a good day.

Comment: You can have your own servlet as a landing page, just add it to the `welcome-file-list`

Comment: `index.jsp` is also a servlet

Comment: Since a `servlet` is typically accessed through an http request, it is sometimes easier to have an html page like `index.jsp` as a stepping stone to the `servlet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly needed.you can direclty call a `servlet.`There is no harm in that.

like

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Interesting, I do not have a "welcome-file-list". Could this be because I created my project with NetBeans?

Comment: Nope.its in web.xml file \

Comment: Ah, thank you. Looks like I need to read more on the web.xml file.

Comment: Please note that the one linked in previous comment has a bad root element declaration. Do not use it. Let your IDE autogenerate one which complies the servlet version of the target container.

Comment: Yeah.Do not copy paste it.That is just for reference.See how the mappings are there and edit your own web.xml file generated by your IDE.Good luck.